# In ansible is it possible to use different users inside role task

Tags: ansible-playbook

In ansible is it possible to use different users inside role task

```
# example: role
#           fuse_star
#              tasks
#                main.yml

- name: start fuse
  command: " start fuse"
  become: yes
  become_user: test1
- name: check fuse service up"
  command: " check fuse"
  become: yes
  become_user: test2
```

Comment: It should be.  Did you try it?  Did you get any errors?

Comment: Yeah look at many postgres playbooks.